# Compile plugin code in Java without parent class body

Tags: java, plugins, compilation, loading, abstract

I´m trying to add a plugin system to my app. I have an abstract class that plugins must extend. This class provide usuful methods so I really need it. The problem is that these plugins could be written by anyone so I suppouse that they'll need the abstract class code to be able to compile their code.

I don´t want to complicate the process of creating a plugin. Is there a way to compile the code without know the abstract class body (only its methods)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to mark one of the answer, [SOLVED] doesn't signify anything here @ SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is there a way to compile the code without know the abstract class body (only its methods)?***

No. In order to to compile a class declared as

```
class A extends B
```

you'll have to have `B` in source format in the source path or in .class format on the class path.

(If knowing only the methods is sufficient for writing the plugin, it sounds more like you're after an interface than an abstract class.)

> ***I don´t want to complicate the process of creating a plugin.***

Providing the compiled .class file of `B` is completely uncomplicated and probably the best practice in this scenario.

Actually, having an API at hand through a .jar-file containing the relevant classes and interfaces is probably the standard.

To be clear:

1. Take the classes that are relevant for plugin-development, compile them, and put them in, say  `pluginapi.jar`
2. Distribute the .jar and tell plugin developers that their plugins should compile, provided the `pluginapi.jar`
3. Ask the plugindevelopers to provide you with `plugin.jar` (not necessarily including pluginapi classes)
4. In your application, make sure that the plugin API classes are present, for instance by including them the class path.
5. Load the plugin classes.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* ask your plugin authors to provide you some classes with some specified methods and invoke those using reflection. This would mean that they could write a plugin that can be compiled without access to any of your code.

**But** it would also severely limit their possibilities: How should the plugin interact with your system if they have no way of calling into it? Since the only sane way to provide that is  to make some classes (or interfaces) accessible, you can just as well provide an interface (or abstract class) that they need to implement/extend.

You could put that interface (and all interfaces/classes visible to plugins) in a separate .jar file. This way they only need that jar file to compile a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide a jar file with all necessry java files. But remember, that once you publish the api, you should be very careful with changing it.

Comment: Mmm, sounds nice. If I do this, do I need to include the jar file with the necessary files inside the plugin jar?

Comment: @David: no, the plugin will probably be loaded by the ClassLoader that runs your code (or a ClassLoader with that CL as the parent). This way  the necessary classes will be available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can go around by not forcing your users to extend a class or implement an interface but have them provide a function with a certain signature -- which then you can call via reflection. In this case they won't need anything from you, however, if they get the function wrong obviously you won't be able to call the plugin.

Comment: Yes, they must provide a function but as they will need to do the same task I want to provide a method to execute the task.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases Java scripting can be very useful. Have your plugins written in Groovy and the codes can be easily (down)loaded and executed in your framework, something like this http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy